# Pandoc Output PDF with Code Block using listing other than verbatim

Tags: verbatim, pandoc, markdown

I using RStudio and Pandoc to output my document created in markdown to PDF. Pandoc always convert the code blocks in markdown using verbatim environment. Does anyone know how to switch the default conversion environment from verbatim to listing?

Comment: I uses Knitr to generate the output, I understand that I can use --listings command, but have not figured how. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 2):

pandoc 1.8 released[1] in 2011 added a `--listings` option to "Use the listings package for LaTeX code blocks" instead of doing the highlighting in pandoc. Refer to the manual: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html.

[1] https://pandoc.org/releases.html#pandoc-1.8-2011-01-30